# Send an E-Mail in Android (In background without using intent_send)

Tags: android, email, android-intent, intentfilter

i am beginner in android !!
I am trying to send an email.
I am taking name, email and feedback from user; i want to send an email to emample@xyz.com with name email and feedback.

I DO NOT WANT TO USE INTENT_SEND or Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

I want to send in background without opening the email intent.

I tried [this](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_(no_Intents)_in_Android) but

[image: this].

Answer (score 0):

You need to essentially create an email client to run in the background, I did this using gmail like so:

```
public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
private String user;
private String password;
private Session session;

static {
    Security.addProvider(new com.{package}.JSSEProvider());
}

public GMailSender(String user, String password) {
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
}

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
}

public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {
    try{
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setDataHandler(handler);
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
        else
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
        Transport.send(message);
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}

public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
    private byte[] data;
    private String type;

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getContentType() {
        if (type == null)
            return "application/octet-stream";
        else
            return type;
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "ByteArrayDataSource";
    }

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        throw new IOException("Not Supported");
    }
}
}
```

and

```
public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

public JSSEProvider() {
    super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
        public Void run() {
            put("SSLContext.TLS",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
            put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
            put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
            put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
            return null;
        }
    });
}
}
```

then use it by doing this

```
GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("gmailUsername", "gmailPassword");
                sender.sendMail("subject",
                        body,
                        "sender",
                        "recipient");
```

I think that's just about it, let me know if it doesn't work, I may be forgetting something haha

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler at com.ainovarobitics.JAESANativeAndroid.GMailSender.sendMail(GMailSender.java:56)

Comment: line no 56 is in GMailSender is DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));

Comment: and when i did this

//sender.sendMail("This is Subject","This is Body","XXXXXX@gmail.com","XXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com");

commented that line everything goes well